# stop a countdown timer after a certain time

Tags: javascript, timer

I have a js countdown timer (Author: ricocheting.com) that counts down to a certain date. It executes like so

```js
window.onload = function() {
      var cdown = new CDown();

      cdown.add(new Date(2015, 8, 06, 15, 55, 00), "countdown-holder");
    };
```

The countdown timer is part of an ad I'd like to run on google ads but google had a 30s limit on the ads, so I'd like to run the countdown for at least those 30 seconds and then make it stop and disappear.

Being a complete and total newbe to coding, the code is a maze for me though I understand that the init function is making the whole countdown work

```js
init: function() {
        this.state = 1;
        var self = this;
        this.interval = window.setInterval(function() {
          self.tick();
        }, 1000);
      },
```

I also figured out that the clearTimeout() stops the countdown

```js
window.clearTimeout(this.interval);
```

Now after searching the net I know there is the setInterval() function that can stop a function from executing after a certain amount of time, so I've tried to put the window.clearTimeout(this.interval) code inside a set interval function but that doesn't seem to work :(

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: You need to use `clearInterval(this.interval)`

Comment: Thank you Arun P Johny. I've trid to play around with that too but didn't make it work :(

Comment: can you share the code for `CDown` or create a demo in snippet/jsfiddle

Comment: Here's the link to the jsfiddle [link](https://jsfiddle.net/vqpc6o28/). First time I use jsfiddle. Hopefully the link will get you to the code.

Comment: so what is the problem.... the timer is stopping after the last item is removed from the list - https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/yzfr27bq/2/

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [`clearInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/clearInterval), [`clearTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/clearTimeout) is used to stop a timer created by [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout) function.

I'd recommend you to use `setTimeout` instead. I made an example script which will call `removeAd` function after 30 seconds.

```
setTimeout(removeAd, 30000); //30 seconds
```

Comment: Thank you Jez. I am trying this out but I must be doing something wrong.

Comment: I tried to use `function myFunction () {
      cdown = setTimeout (windown.onload, 3000);
    }` but that doesn't work

Comment: I also tried `setTimeout(function() {window.clearTimeout(this.interval);}, 3000);` but no luck there either...Like I said, a complete maze to me....I mean I understand what the different methods do but don't really understand how they work inside my code :(

Comment: Jez, thank you for taking time to respond. You were right I did misspell a word and thank you for the tip in the PS....but still no luck. The timer doesn't stop at all :(

Comment: Jez I don't know what Steam is sorry (: Are you talking the about steamcommunity. com for game enthusiasts (;

Comment: thank you Jez and @Arun P Johny for getting involved and your help! I eventually got help from the creator of the countdown timer and thanks to your suggestions was close to getting it right. `window.setTimeout(function() {
            window.clearInterval(self.interval)
          }, 3000);` which should have been placed in the init function.